# Matlab 3D plot quadratic?

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

How to plot a 3d graph of a quadratic funciton.
Here is my code for the 2D plot is there anyway to adapt it for a 3d code ?

```
z = (startv2:step:endv2);
y = (a2.*(z.^2))+(b2.*z)+c2;
plot(z,y);
text(value1,0, ['X1 = ',num2str(value1),' ']);
text(value2,0, ['X2 = ',num2str(value2)]);
grid
```

Comment: I think you want `surf`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html you'll also find `meshgrid` very helpful in defining your X and Y matrices for the plot

Comment: thx for that but i have never done it before, what is a meshgrid, can i use z to creat the meshgrid ?

Comment: No, meshgrid is a function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html you'd want something like `[X, Y] = meshgrid(xmin:xstep:xmax, ymin:ystep:ymax)`, especially if `Z` is either a 2D matrix or can be written as a function of `X` and `Y`

Answer (score 1):

These MATLAB functions might help:

[`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html)

or

[`contour3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html)

or

[`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)

depending on what you want to show. The MATLAB help (click on the functions above) has examples for all of them.

Comment: i managed to do it with plot3 but i was thinking more of something like that : https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+plotting+quadratic+function&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=rreLUY_VOqTF0QW1m4CADQ&biw=1046&bih=1072&sei=sLeLUYuPGvPK0AWbyoCgDA#imgrc=edDNVbY4uoi5NM%3A%3BstVbUD1sGFDNuM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Feconc10.bu.edu%252FGENEC%252Fimages%252Fgrafy%252Fquad3d_anim.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Feconc10.bu.edu%252FGENEC%252FBasics%252FFunGraphs%252Ffungrquad3d.htm%3B316%3B279